# Does one need to be relatively good at mathematics to become a decent programmer?

Tags: algorithm, math, theory

I would like to apologise for the vagueness of this question, but please bear with me, I will try to put it into context.

I've been trying to find some good exercises on the Internet that would allow me to become a better programmer. I feel like I know enough syntax but lack a programmer's mind. These are general programming exercises, nothing fancy. However, I've noticed that the vast majority of them involve mathematical problems (from very basic ones to ones I can't even understand in English, let alone C). There's the famous Project Euler, for instance, but many other websites as well. Furthermore, all the algorithms (I mean, the books/tutorials that teach general algorithms) are obviously very mathematical. All these log(2n) and such.

I really enjoy programming as a hobby and can generally understand the basic ins and outs of whatever language I am learning. I have been doing it for a number of years know, just for my own pleasure. I can solve the aforementioned problems in terms of programming/language, by utilising "brute force" solutions, writing everything out on a piece of paper, using a calculator and so on.

The problem is that I perfectly and soberly realise that I simply do not have the necessary mathematical understanding to comprehend the "true" solutions behind these problems. I feel like I'm cheating. I simply have no mental capacity to figure out these clever algorithmical solutions to most of the problems on Euler, nor do I have the necessary mathematical background. When their own solution paper explains that you can do this solution better and in a more clever way, I get lost instantly. That's one of the reasons I never went to a CS school, because in my country you need a very, very thorough understanding of algebra and physics in order to get into one. I sort of skipped straight into actual programming and thus it became my hobby, not my profession.

Now I'm not young anymore and have come to admit I will never understand the mathematical side of programming as a true programmer should. So I would like to ask: is mathematics really important for accomplishing non-trivial tasks?

For instance, I would like to develop some 2D games. Will I get by with cheating by looking up whatever trigonometry I need for a given task, without really understanding it? Will I ever accomplish anything that way?

Thank you and sorry if that didn't make sense. Could you please just share your experience and maybe point me in the right direction. I feel like I'm learning to read without knowing the alphabet...

Comment: Half the questions in the "related" site bar are very similar, if not identical. Without doubt, there are many more (and some more over at [programmers.SE]). Not all of them directly mention maths, because not all of your question is about maths. Please do some research, it saves not only our time but also yours.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about career/educational advice, and is not a specific programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines. It is also a duplicate of at least half a dozen previous questions on the same topic, such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52176/what-are-the-core-mathematical-concepts-a-good-developer-should-know?rq=1) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107059/how-much-mathematics-and-physics-should-a-programmer-know?rq=1), for instance.

Comment: I beg to differ. The questions in the related site bar are either too advanced (i.e. which PART of math should I know?) or unrelated. I understand if my question doesn't belong here at all, for that I say sorry, but I haven't found a question as general as mine. And this isn't career advice, my career has nothing to do with programming. It's essentially the same question as "Should I learn X?" of which there are plenty here.

Comment: It depends on your expectation from a "Decent " programmer. I've seen many programmers who have just basic mathematics knowledge. You won't see many programmers who do know vector analysis well. But from my experience, great programmers do a lot of mathematics. Nobody would like to submit a search query and wait for days to process that. Learn algorithm runtime analysis (O(), T()), Dynamic Programming etc and your end users will thank you for the speed of your awesome app :)

Comment: @Gleb I concede the claim about related question being "very similar". But it doesn't take a monolithic general question covering these exact subjects to help you. The "I feel I don't actually know anything" sentiment is very common and has been addressed several times, and I'll be damned if some of those don't speak to you. See e.g. [I'm graduating with a Computer Science degree but I don't feel like I know how to program](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/43528/7043)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot think of how to reword my question, because I was/still am asking exactly what I've written, i.e. not which area  of math should a programmer learn, but if my ignorance of math would greatly hinder any progress I might make as a hobbyist programmer. I once again sincerely apologise if this doesn't belong here, but this is the only sensible community I know and I was hoping for some honest opinion from not just anyone, but the people here who prove time and time again that they are the best of the best. If I did indeed break the rules, please delete this question.

Answer (score 2):

Programming and mathematics are related but very different things.

For some programming problems you will need to do a lot of maths. For example 3d graphics, physics, simulations, even financial packages, etc.

On the other hand though other programming problems involve virtually no math at all. Creating a web page, calling a web service, designing a user interface, etc.

These are all problems with very little math involved - and things that are just as important as the more math-intensive problems.